# Solving a summation of $\frac{1}{1+ab^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a problem of the form $$\sum_{j,k} \frac{1}{1+a(R_{jk})^x} = c$$ where I already know $a$, $b$, $c$, and $R$ (which is a matrix). I am unsure of how to solve for $x$, given everything is inside the summation sign. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to solve?

Comment: Even with scalars, it would be impossible